# Whats the proper way to use date and interval in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to implement this filter in SQLalchemy, with a MySQL database

`dmb.manifest_date >= (CURDATE() - interval 7 day)`

What I did is

```
date_filter=(datetime.today()-timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
.filter(DayManifestBatch.manifest_date>= cast(date_filter,DATE))
```

I imported DATE and cast from SQLALchemy. Also tried with just the string date and datetime format but I always get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'> instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way but you can use:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

.filter(DayManifestBatch.manifest_date >= text('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY'))
```